# Best way to send data with React Router <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a profile card component with an 'edit profile' icon in the top right-hand corner of the card.  Upon clicking the icon, the user is routed to the `/editprofile` endpoint.  Right now, I'm using React Router's  to get the job done.  I'm sending along the logged-in user information inside the  component and using props.location to fetch in the ProfileEdit component, but obviously when I refresh the page, that user information is lost.  What is the best way to handle this situation?  I haven't been using React Context, but thought that might be a viable solution.  Are there any other solutions that wouldn't require me to wire up Context?  Below is my ProfileCard component:

```
function NewProfileCard({ user }) {
  const id = window.localStorage.getItem('id')

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={{
        pathname: `/profile/${id}/edit`,
        user: user
      }}>
        <Icon 
          name='edit' 
          size='large'
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you are using `user` for many components (which I assume you are / will be as the app scales), then you definitely want to consider React Context or Redux (or Mobx some state manager). However, with state managers, only use them if you absolutely have to as it can create unnecessary bloat in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass state in your link. Then access the state from location.

Your Link will look like this:

```js
<Link 
  to={{
    pathname: `/profile/${id}/edit`,
    state: { user } 
   }}
>
   <Icon 
      name='edit' 
      size='large'
    />
</Link>
```

This will pass an object with key `user` and value `user` which you can access like so:

```js
const { user } = props.location.state
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing profile of the current logged in user, I think you should store it in redux and use redux-persist to persist it in localstorage. This can solve 2 of your problem

- Any component that need access to this info just need to connect to redux
- With redux persist your data won't be lost on reload

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use localStorage to store them. But if the users don't provide access to their localStorage you have to choose other options to store.

In case you need the props to be in the state of the component you're navigating to, pathname: `/profile/${id}/edit`, then you can you use `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state by the props you're receiving and then store them in the `localStorage`.